# Can I use "malloc" for local variables to return local variables?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char * upperCase(const char* s)
{
    char * ret = NULL;
    size_t length = strlen(s) + 1;
    ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        ret[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    char* ret = NULL;
    char* input = "HelloWorld";
    ret = upperCase(input);
    printf("value = %s", ret);
    free(ret);
}
```

> The above code takes a string as a parameter and copies the string. It
> then converts each element of the copied string to uppercase and
> returns it.
>
> Compiler = GCC 6.2

If you use the malloc function, is it possible to return a local variable to terminate the function and release the memory? I do not have enough understanding of the scope that still has memory.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The issue is with returning pointers to things that don’t exist anymore, but what you `malloc` continues to exist until you `free` it. Another option is to take an output pointer as an argument so the memory management is left to the caller.

Comment: `sizeof (char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: `toupper(s[i])` has undefined behavior if `s[i]` is negative. You should cast it to `unsigned char`.

Comment: 1. Did the compiler complain? 2. Did gdb complain? If 1 and 2 were both NO, you're good to go.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That seems like very bad advice.

Comment: It's a start...

Comment: @COLDSPEED. I'm confused. Are you saying "If a C program compiles then it can't have bugs or leaks?" Are you saying "You should always run your C program under a debugger"?

Comment: YunjinJang Curious: why `(char*)` cast in `ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);`? Why multiple by `sizeof(char)` which is 1?  Who or what text suggested that?

Comment: @chux The reason for casting is that I know that the "malloc" function requires casting because the return type is "void *". And I use "sizeof ()" because I have seen a lot of things that are mainly used for other types, not char types. I was mistaken as to how to use char type like this too.

Comment: @YunjinJang In C, the cast is _not_ required.  Consider `ret = malloc(sizeof *ret * length);` for its ease to code right, review and maintain.

Comment: @chux Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @melpomene why should s[i] be negative if the input is an ascii string? wouldn't casting to unsigned char be obsolete?

Comment: @CIsForCookies *if the input is an ascii string* - yes, "if". Why make such an assumption in a general `upperCase` function? ASCII only covers half of the possible `char` values on my system.

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**: Yes, it is possible

**Long answer**: `malloc(some_size)` allocates `some_size` space and returns a pointer to the address of the start of the allocated chunk (or `NULL` upon failure). When doing `ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);` ret is assigned with said pointer that points to memory chunk of `length` `char`s (note that `sizeof(char) == 1` so you can remove it).

The memory is yours until you free it, even after the function had returned, so, after the end of `upperCase(...)` execution, that memory still belongs to you. The only problem is, the pointer `ret` was allocated on the stack with `(auto)` local storage, meaning it will *"die"* when it's scope (in your case - the `upperCase(...)` function's scope), and thus, you will not know where that memory is, **BUT** since you return `ret` from the function, the value it holds (which is the address to your allocated memory) will pass on to `main`'s `ret`, which basically means you're good to go.

One last thing I think I should emphasize is, returning local variables is done all the time. For example `int increment_by_one(int x){int y = x + 1; return y;}`. This is a very simple function that returns the value of local `int y`. Since the value returned is all we need (i.e. the value of `x+1`) it's ok that it (the value) was stored in a local variable. The same (sort of) goes for your case - since `ret` inside `upperCase` holds the address that was allocated ,it's ok for it to *"die"* after `upperCase` ends, since the value it holds (the address) is passed on.

```
char * upperCase(const char* s)
{
    char * ret = NULL;                             // local variable -> will die after upperCase ends
    size_t length = strlen(s) + 1;                 // local variable -> will die after upperCase ends
    ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);    // ret assigned with address to memory
    for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++) {          // local variable -> will die after it's scope (the for loop) ends
        ret[i] = toupper(s[i]);
    }
    return ret;                                     // said address is returned to main (local variable ret now dies peacefully after fulfilling its duty) 
}

int main()
{
    char* ret = NULL;               // local variable -> will die after main ends
    char* input = "HelloWorld";     // local variable -> will die after main ends
    ret = upperCase(input);         // ret gets the address allocated in upperCase
    printf("value = %s", ret);
    free(ret);                      // address is freed
}
```

2 notes:

1. There is no need casting malloc return value, meaning `ret = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * length);` should be `ret = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);`
2. no need for `sizeof(char)` since it's `1`, meaning you can shorten it further to `ret = malloc(length);`
3. `malloc` can fail. In that case it will return `NULL` so after every `ret = malloc(...);` you should check the value like `if(!ret){// handle error}` or `if(ret != NULL){// do something}` and such

Comment: There is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and ***always*** validate the return of `malloc` (e.g. in `main()`  (before `printf` and `free`) you need, at minimum, `if (ret) {/* do stuff */}` or `if (!ret) { /* handle error, or exit */ }`. Otherwise good answer and effort.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin saying casting malloc is unnecessary is exactly what I meant. I'll edit to make it clearer. About the `if(!ret)`, I mentioned that `malloc` can return NULL, but I didn't want to change the OP's code

Comment: Yes, it looked like a copy/paste issue from the original question, but it is always worth cleaning up so learning by the OP or many who may follow will occur `;)`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can.

The `malloc` memory is on the heap, so it won't release when `upperCase` end.

But variable `char *ret` is on the stack, it will be popped out when `upperCase` end. But the value of `ret` in `upperCase()` is copied via `ret = upperCase(input)` in `main()`. That is to say, you still obtain the address of the allocated memory, which is still on the heap. You can call `free(ret)` when finished the use of this memory.

---

Check [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for details about stack & heap.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can understand some of the things I was not sure about. It has helped a lot.